# Harder-Narasimhan over arbitrary coefficients

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be an $n$ dimensional smooth projective variety over $k$. Let $H$ be a hyperplane section. Define the slope $\mu(E)=\frac{c_1(E).H^{n-1}}{rank(E)}$ for vector bundles on $X$. Does the Harder-Narasimhan filtration exist in the following cases? and is it unique?

1) $k$ is a field that is not algebraically closed.

2) $k$ is the ring of integers of a number field.

Comment: The answer to (1) is "yes" -- the Harder-Narasimhan filtration defined over $\bar k$ descends canonically to $k$, and hence exists and is unique.